# How to put data using Json File on highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

```
var chartData;

$(function(){
$.ajax({

url: 'http://localhost:3300/temp',
type: 'GET',
dataType: "json",
success : function(data) {
  chartData = data;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(chartData));

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart-location',
        type: 'line',
        marginRight: 130,
        marginBottom: 25, 
        height : 400,

    },
    title: {
        text: 'Packet Number',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: data["categories"]
    },


    series: [
     {
        name: 'paketNo',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        data: chartData
      }
    ]
});
 chart.render();
}
   });
 });
```

---

My JSON file:

```
{
  "dataset": [{
    "seriesname": "Topic 22",
    "data": [{
      "value": 0
    }, {
      "value": 1
    }, {
      "value": 0
    }, {
      "value": 0
    }, {
      "value": 0
    }]
  }]
}
```

I want to display value parameter , but nothing is display when I use the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong format, `highcharts` accept data like this:

```
data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
```

But you passed whole `JSON` to data. So, you should get values only, you can do like below:

```js
var obj = {
  "dataset": [{
    "seriesname": "Topic 22",
    "data": [{
      "value": 0
    }, {
      "value": 1
    }, {
      "value": 0
    }, {
      "value": 0
    }, {
      "value": 0
    }]
  }]
};

var array = [];

$.each(obj.dataset[0].data,function(i,v){
array.push(obj.dataset[0].data[i].value);
});

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now pass values to data:

```
 series: [
     {
        name: 'paketNo',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        data: array
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @AshishGoyal Glad to help. Please accept this answer by click on `check` icon and click on up vote if it solve your problem.

Comment: Need More help in this , can you provide me your email id so that we can talk there ?